# Is the magnetic field in a coil misrepresented or miscalculated?

Tags: magnetic-fields

The magnetic field is usually (mis)represented as a rotating flux:

[image]

but if we consider a charge in the middle of the coil and analyze what really happens, we notice that the field is not homogeneous and the charge is pushed around in every direction.(blue arrows)

But, because of the sin law, some directions produce less actual  force than others, yet many opposite forces cancel out. There will always be a resulting net force that will make thecharge rotate.

My question is: is the magnetic field/force in a coil overestimated, or do the current explanations/derivations take into account the fact that many opposite forces cancel out?

Comment: Why would the magnetic field push around the (presumably not moving) charge in every direction?

Comment: @user1583209, you can see that the positive charge in the picture has a small vector pointing to the right, which determines the upward direction, if it were negative the pull would be reversed. A charge can never be still, anyway, as you probably know!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please consider improving it. However in answer to your question(last lines), yes, the field is calculated theoretically for an ideal coil is perfectly isotropic w.r.t the central axis. The isotropy of the coil is enough to justify the symmetry of the field lines about this axis.

Comment: @Lelouch, the strength of the field at any point is the sum of thousands of forces in every direction, right? does the theoretical evaluation take that into account? I never read about that, how is it calculated by an integral or what? In the center of the coil the net sum of all opposing forces is exactly zero if the sine law is not considered, is that right?